# Why the return response is coming in weird format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am learning the backend in node. I am trying to execute the following piece of code
`

```
const axios= require('axios')
async function getData(){
    const resp = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    console.log('hello',resp.data)
}

getData()
```

I am getting output like this:
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V1fG.png)

The expected output is: [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQDpE.png)

I tried running code with `node index.js` and with extension `code runner`. The output is the same, even on replit I am getting the same result.
Can someone explain, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are recieving a [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) (`br`) encoding. Just pass `Accept-Encoding` header to `deflate` and the server will return you a json output.

```js
await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate'
    }
})
```

Comment: The server doesn't support the `deflate` encoding and is as good as passing no encoding.

Comment: I prefer `'gzip, deflate'` over just `'deflate'`

Comment: But just gzip doesn't solve the issue. `gzip` is an extra.

Comment: @Jonathan. If don't then why this message changes only if you insert the "deflate" option?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's just that [axios currently doesn't decompress Brotli-encoded resposes](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1635), yet signals Brotli as an acceptable encoding anyway, hence why it looks like garbage. Instead of disabling compression completely, just send the supported encodings axios does support and decompression should be invisible to you

```
const resp = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is't any problem with your code and also it gives me exactly the output you required with the code you posted in the question so it must be either other log or some other problem but your code posted in question works fine with below output.
[image]