# axios returning specials unicode block as data in getStaticProps in next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, function, next.js

[here is the code and the data result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8PIW.jpg)

I tried with fetch method it works, but with 'axios' it did not

Answer (score 0):

From my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673668/10827693):

---

You are recieving a [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) (`br`) encoding. Just pass `Accept-Encoding` header to `deflate` and the server will return you a json output.

```js
await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate'
    }
})
```